# Filling empty value in mysql time series for grafana status timeline dashboard

Tags: mysql, grafana

I've used transformation on grafana to turn a mysql table that looks like this:

| timestamp | device | state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-09 10:01:33 | device A | Online |
| 2022-08-09 10:02:33 | device B | Online |

into this

| timestamp | device A | device B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-09 10:01:33 | Online |  |
| 2022-08-09 10:02:33 |  | Online |

I'm now trying to fill the empty cells with 'Offline'.
How can I replace the empty cells?

**Note**: I'm using the state timeline panel to display my time series data.

Answer (score 0):

Use case statements:

```
SELECT 
  `timestamp`, 
  (CASE WHEN device='device A' AND state='Online' THEN state ELSE 'Offline' END) deviceA,
  (CASE WHEN device='device B' AND state='Online' THEN state ELSE 'Offline' END) deviceB 
FROM `device_status`
```